# NSButton key equivalent

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsbutton

I can't make a key equivalent work on an NSButton that I have created programatically.  Can anyone advise me of what I'm doing wrong? The button works as intended when pressed, but the key equivalent will not work.

```
NSButton *ESCButton = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 10, 10)];
[[quickEntryWindow contentView] addSubview:ESCButton];
[[ESCButton cell] setKeyEquivalent:@"\E"];
[ESCButton setTarget:self];
//[ESCButton setTransparent:YES];
[ESCButton setAction:@selector(hideQuickEntryWindow)];
[quickEntryWindow setDefaultButtonCell:[ESCButton cell]];
[quickEntryWindow enableKeyEquivalentForDefaultButtonCell];
```

Comment: Try hitting the `enter` key and see whether it works !

Comment: Why are you making it the default button cell? A default button cell uses `\r` (Return/Enter) as its key equivalent.

Comment: Well that worked. I don't know why I thought I had to make it the default button cell. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-setDefaultButtonCell:` turns the cell into the window default button cell, which necessarily has key equivalent `\r` (Return/Enter). If you want to use another key equivalent, remove

```
[quickEntryWindow setDefaultButtonCell:[ESCButton cell]];
[quickEntryWindow enableKeyEquivalentForDefaultButtonCell];
```